# How to install Kubernetes on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: kubernetes, windows-server, windows-server-2016

A few weeks ago the Windows Server 2019 was announced as Preview with native Kubernetes Support.

Is there any documentation how to activate or install Kubernetes?
I already set up a virtual server (with Desktop Feature) on my local Hyper-V, but I can not find *any* hint to test the preview features of Kubernetes on Windows Server 2019.

Or do I misunderstand the current Preview notes and Kubernetes is only announced but not available yet?

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes and its Windows cni plugins are [in beta at the time of writing](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/01/kubernetes-v19-beta-windows-support/) and insider build 1803 doesn't have any features/role for it (neither does `dockeree` though).

There are installation instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/getting-started-kubernetes-windows).

I've not found any information on what *precisely* is new in Server 2019 for Kubernetes...

Would be great to have powershell `Install-Module`/`Install-Package` for installation and a Windows Admin Center plugins for administering a cluster.